# Сетевой интерфейс относится к описанию сетевого драйвера сетевого устройства или что эта за сущность?

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, tcp-ip

Можно набрать ifconfig получить список сетевых интерфейсов, что интерфейс предоставляет взаимодействие одного уровня модели OSI другому, но мне хочется абстрактно понять как пакет достигает приложения и что описывает сетевой интерфейс, полученный командой ifconfig. По проводам пришел пакет, записался он в буфер сетевого адаптера, драйвер сетевой карты вызвал прерывание, ОС пошла и забрала эти данные своим модулем (реализация которых лежит в /net), дальше уже ОС отдала нужно процессу. Понимаю что есть сетевая карта у нее есть MAC адреc, есть сетевой уровень например по протоколу ip это ip адрес, а сетевой интерфейс описывает вот как раз это взаимодействие и его использует и драйвер сетевой карты и модуль из ядра? Вот такая каша этих взаимодействий, понимаю протоколов и реализаций много, и как это может быть устроено специфично, но вот составить пазл кто кого вызывает и что все таки описывает сетевой интерфейс хочется уложить в голове.

Comment: OSI существует только в учебниках. в реальных ОС оно не нужно.

Comment: Сетевой интерфейс описывает настройки взаимодействия модулей, а какой ип/мак адрес нацепить на пакет и в какой буфер его засунуть для отправки